# How to Handle sql_Variant sql datatype using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis, sqldatatypes, sql-variant

I am using the power shell to execute one of the stored procedure which has one of the parameter with the datatype sql_Variant and resided in the SSISDB (System stored procedure)

As sql_variant supports multi datatype I am passing int,string & boolean data types.

stored procedure executing fine when I pass the string data type. but not the int and boolean.

Procedure Name is

> Catalog.Set_Object_Parameter_Value

It has one Parameter with the datatype SQL_Variant. Below is screen shot.

[image]

While Inputting value based of some condition I will get int/string/bool datatype.

How Can I Handle/Convert those value to Sql_Variant data type before input using Power-shell.

Currently my power-shell command something like below.

```
$procSignature = "EXEC [catalog].[set_object_parameter_value] @object_type,@folder_name,@project_name,@parameter_name,@parameter_value,@object_name";
                            $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
                            $cmd.Connection = $catalogConnection;
                            $cmd.CommandText = $procSignature;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@object_type", $Scope ) | Out-Null;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folder_name", $FolderName ) | Out-Null;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_name", $ProjectName ) | Out-Null;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", $ParmeterName ) | Out-Null;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_value", $ParmeterValue ) | Out-Null;
                            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@object_name", $object ) | Out-Null;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the error? I suppose the issue is with the stored procedure, *not* the powershell script.

Comment: Can you not use [string]$ParameterValue in place of $ParameterValue?

Comment: @marsze Since it is system stored procedure i don't think so it is an issue with stored procedure.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - I got the following Error Message.      Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'Boolean'." Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'Boolean'." Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0"

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with exactly the same SP. Try this:

```
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_value", $ParameterValue -As $ParameterValue.GetType().Name) | Out-Null;
```

Comment: It is not able to handle Boolean Values.

Comment: That's true. In the end, I made the UI which feeds this have a drop-down for the parameter type too. It's too messy/impossible to deal with SQL variants in PowerShell and have things guessed correctly.